# Predicted coefficients from LASSO cannot display the right Header of coefficients for large sample

Tags: r, predict, lasso-regression

I am running a regression using LASSO for a dataset with 102 predictors. the dataset was correctly read,and names(murder) gives me the correct Header.

```
>library(glmnet)
>murder=read.csv(file="CommViolPredUnnormalizedData.csv", header = TRUE)
```

After getting the best lambda from cv.glmnet, I would like to predict the coefficients using the best lambda. However, the results changes Header name after the 26th coefficients, the Header of coefficients copy that of the 26th and add 5 digits of numbers at the end. such that I have the rest 77 coefficients naming after OtherPerCapxxxxx, as shown below. Is it because by default predict(.. type="coefficients") can only save up to 26 Headers of coefficients? Thanks a lot.

```
>lasso.out=glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,family="gaussian",lambda=grid)
>lasso.coef=predict(lasso.out,type="coefficients",s=bestlam2)[1:103,]
>lasso.coef
(Intercept)       population    householdsize     racePctBlack     racePctWhite 
 15.68589291       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.07242063      -0.12888132 
racePctAsian      racePctHisp      agePct12t21      agePct12t29      agePct16t24 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
  agePct65up        numbUrban         pctUrban        medIncome         pctWWage 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
pctWFarmSelf       pctWInvInc       pctWSocSec      pctWPubAsst       pctWRetire 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
   medFamInc        perCapInc      whitePerCap      blackPerCap     indianPerCap 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
 AsianPerCap     **OtherPerCap0 OtherPerCap10000** OtherPerCap10004 OtherPerCap10005 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10011 OtherPerCap10012 OtherPerCap10028 OtherPerCap10031 OtherPerCap10040 
  0.23747627       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10043 OtherPerCap10044 OtherPerCap10045 OtherPerCap10046 OtherPerCap10048 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10050 OtherPerCap10051 OtherPerCap10063 OtherPerCap10082 OtherPerCap10088 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10095 OtherPerCap10102 OtherPerCap10113 OtherPerCap10114 OtherPerCap10115 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10118 OtherPerCap10133 OtherPerCap10146 OtherPerCap10152 OtherPerCap10156 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10159  OtherPerCap1016 OtherPerCap10162 OtherPerCap10164 OtherPerCap10166 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10173 OtherPerCap10174 OtherPerCap10176 OtherPerCap10182 OtherPerCap10195 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10205 OtherPerCap10217 OtherPerCap10218 OtherPerCap10219  OtherPerCap1022 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10221 OtherPerCap10244 OtherPerCap10249 OtherPerCap10250 OtherPerCap10254 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10257 OtherPerCap10262 OtherPerCap10272 OtherPerCap10276 OtherPerCap10277 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10280 OtherPerCap10290 OtherPerCap10295 OtherPerCap10300 OtherPerCap10301 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10315 OtherPerCap10317 OtherPerCap10321 OtherPerCap10329 OtherPerCap10333 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10337 OtherPerCap10348 OtherPerCap10351 OtherPerCap10359 OtherPerCap10362 
  0.00000000       0.00000000      -1.49402709       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10381 OtherPerCap10385 OtherPerCap10394 OtherPerCap10395  OtherPerCap1040 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000 
OtherPerCap10401 OtherPerCap10423 OtherPerCap10425 
  0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000
```

Comment: It looks like `OtherPerCap` is a character vector. It seems like you might want to change it to a numeric type before using the `model.matrix` function.

Comment: Thank you Mike.Gahan, but $OtherperCap is a numeric vector, it is of the same type as the coefficients before it.

Comment: So `col.names(x)` doesn't return 77 variables for `OtherPerCap`?